# What is "pursue an agenda" meaning?

Tags: meaning, dictionaries

I have read a "pursue" word meaning here https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pursue?q=pursue, but I can't understand the second meaning, especially one of its examples.

The meaning described there is:

```
to continue to discuss, find out about or be involved in something
```

And there is example below:

```
 to pursue an agenda/a strategy/a claim
```

What does the "to pursue an agenda" mean in the context of the world definition mentioned above?
To continue to discuss an agenda?
To continue to find out about agenda?
To continue to be involved in an agenda?

I'm not sure about correctness of all of these interpretations. I tried to turn on imagination, but I can't figure out the relationship of this word's description and the example given

Comment: The first meaning for **pursue** given by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pursue) is *Follow or chase (someone or something)*. This particular word may be used when there are distractions or difficulties when trying to keep to an agenda, or the agenda is a long-term goal or policy, rather than just for a meeting.

Comment: Yes, it seems I have understood its meaning in the context of "follow something", but the meaning from oxfordlearnersdictionaries has confused me and got some misunderstanding regarding to its "agenda" example

Comment: They give 9 examples of the way **pursue** can be used in section two. When you pursue something, you don't let it go, or you follow a course of action, or try to reach some goal. Perhaps a [thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/pursue?s=t) will help. When pursuing an agenda, it as as my first comment.

Comment: So, oxfordlearnersdictionaries has some inconsistency between word's second meaning and its example? Because I can't see some accordance of "to continue to discuss, find out about or be involved in something" with "Follow or chase (someone or something)"

Comment: **Pursue** has several shades of meaning, not one fixed meaning. Suppose someone wants talk about apples when the meeting is about pears. You pursue the agenda because you have not finished. You continue to discuss pears.

Comment: *Agenda* also has more than one meaning—from a list of topics for a meeting to a goal or purpose, as @Hotlicks points out in his answer.

Comment: Living example: A boy seeks to date a girl who wants only friendship. Because of his agenda, he asks her to a movie. Romance is his agenda, and asking for the date is how he **pursues** his agenda. When he invites her to a candlelit dinner, his pursuing has crossed the line into stalking. Also, his agenda does not actually include her and her wishes, except in his fantasy. To pursue an agenda implies ignoring your surroundings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the  expression “[pursue  or push an agenda](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/agenda)”, the term agenda is used in the following sense:

> the intention behind what somebody says or does, that is often secret.

> - They were pursuing their own agenda.
> - I'm not trying to push any agenda here.

(Oxford Learner’s Dictionary)

Used  in political and other contexts:

> This weekend, sources at rival stores hit back, accusing them of pushing an agenda.
> From: *Times, Sunday Times (2013)*

> But politicians have pushed the green agenda to the fore so most people are aware of what needs to be done.
> From: *Times, Sunday Times (2007)*

> It's the same people pushing the same agenda.
> From: *The Sun (2015)*

[(Collins)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/push-an-agenda)

Answer (score 1):

"Pursue an agenda" is an idiom, implying the narrow-minded pursuit of a specific goal.  Probably most often used in a political sense, where a politician might "pursue an agenda" aimed at implementing some policy or law, though it would certainly be seen in some business contexts as well.